# Recursion in Single File Components Vue.js 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How to use recursive components in Vue3?

Using recursive components in Vue 3 like normal components causes error `Cannot access before initialization`

*Tree.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <Tree v-if="hasChildren" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Tree from './Tree.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Tree
  },

  setup() {

    const hasChildren = someExitRecursionCondition();

    return {
      hasChildren
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#using-components):

> An SFC can implicitly refer to itself via its filename.

Component can be imported via its filename, but without listing in in the `components` setup object. However, it is enough to use the named component in the template without importing it.

*Tree.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <Tree v-if="hasChildren" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

    const hasChildren = someExitRecursionCondition();

    return {
      hasChildren
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to have `import Tree`, it's tree-shaken in regular `script` , and it infers `components` in `script setup`, which may cause a recursion again

Answer (score 1):

You could provide only the component name option :

```html
<template>
  <Tree v-if="hasChildren" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  name:'Tree',
  setup() {

    const hasChildren = someExitRecursionCondition();

    return {
      hasChildren
    }
  }
</script>
```